# 'event' is deprecated , what can I use instead?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react js and I am novice
the error : the event parametre can't be passed throw the onClick function
this is the piece of code that throws the error (the event parametre is line throwed in code I can't show that)

```
 <div id="notifications__item" onClick={()=>zaa(e-v-e-n-t-)} key={index} >
  <div className="notifications__item__avatar">
    <img src="https://github.com/Flat-Pixels/Notifications-card-animation/raw/master/img/avatar_1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div className="notifications__item__content">
    <span className="notifications__item__title">{notif.message}</span>
    <span className="notifications__item__message">{notif.message}</span>
  </div> 

  
</div>
))}
```

Comment: Your onClick handler doesn't take the event, and tries to pass a _subtraction?!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you are trying to use window event instead of the one passed to the onClick callback.

Simply do `onClick={(event) => zaa(event)}` and the message should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `event` to your function. You can choose any one from the following two.

1. `<div id="notifications__item" onClick={zaa} key={index} >`

or

2. `<div id="notifications__item" onClick={(event) => zaa(event)} key={index} >`